# Seasonal ARIMA Forecast

Tags: forecasting, arima, seasonality

I'm studying ARIMA at the moment with application to seasonal data sets. R lets you forecast using selected models but I'm just wondering what formula is used to compute these forecasts. For example, if we take an $\text{ARIMA}(0,0,0)(0,0,1)_{12}$ of the form:

$$y_t = \alpha + \beta \epsilon_{t-12} + \epsilon_t$$

Then if we have $n$ observation, what will the forecast be for $\hat{y}_{n+k}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,12$, $k=13,14,\ldots,24$ and so on. Also, how do we compute the respective 95% confidence intervals?

Any explanation on this would be appreciated.

Comment: A quick pointer ... forecasting of ARIMA models is discussed in basic terms [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/8).  [I hope a full answer appears, though]

Comment: This looks like a home assignment to me.